# how to find average from array in php

Tags: php

have an array like this

```
$dragonball = [
    [
        "respondent" => "Son go",
        "question1" => "95",
        "question2" => "90",
        "question3" => "80"
    ],
    [
        "respondent" => "Son gohan",
        "question1" => "85",
        "question2" => "80",
        "question3" => "95"
    ],
    [
        "respondent" => "Son go",
        "question1" => "75",
        "question2" => "90",
        "question3" => "90"
    ]
];
```

how to find average of question 1, question2, and question3 ?

> expected it will show like this
> average question1 =>
> average question2 =>
> average question3 =>

Comment: You want to transpose these columns and average?  I'm pretty sure this has already been asked.  See how far you get with this duplicate page.  Then please only ask a new question after you have made a coding attempt (and show it in your question body).  I acknowledge that your first column cannot be summed/averaged, so you will need to remove/ignore that column when processing.